# Is there an excel formula that I can use to sum all blue font numbers from a string in one cell to another?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying to sum all numbers in a string that appear in parentheses from one cell to another.

There is other alphanumeric characters, so I've used some VBA code I found to change all items within parentheses to the color blue. Now I'd like to sum all those numbers into another cell, and have it update automatically.

I'm using Kutools add-in for Excel, and I tried the sumbyfontcolor, but that is for a range, whereas I'm only referencing one cell.

Here's one of the cell's contents that I'd like to extract and sum the numbers from:

```
SM($20.00),RCP($25.65),PMP($612.50)12.25 Hrs T-2,M-7.25,S/G-1.5,Insp/Assy-1.5,C&R($65.00)
```

The example above doesn't show it, but the dollar amounts are in blue:

[image: image of cell]

Comment: By the font, no there is not a formula that can sum by the format of a cell.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the string as text so we can see more what you mean

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly.  I've edited my original question to include an example

Comment: `I've used some VBA code I found to change all items within parentheses to the color blue` - take that same code and make it sum the values instead of painting them blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an array formula that will parse the string and add the numbers contained inside the `()`

```
=SUM(IFERROR(--TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(","")))))*999+1,FIND(")",MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(",REPT(" ",999)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"(","")))))*999+1,999))-1)),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Scott.  There was a problem with the version of Excel that my worksheet is saved as, so I couldn't get it to work on that.  I was able to get your solution to work in a new workbook though.  I won't be able to use your solution because the excel format that I have to stick with is 97-2003 Excel, so other employees can access it.  Thank you though for a working solution that I'll use on my own excel worksheets.

Comment: @MichaelOlson try the edited formula.  It will work on the older style.

Answer (score 0):

if all of the numbers you are looking for are enclosed in () then you could use a function like the following:

```
Function SumFromString(ByVal str As String) As Double
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
        For i = 1 To Len(str)
            If Mid(str, i, 1) = "(" Then
                j = InStr(i, str, ")", vbTextCompare)
                SumFromString = SumFromString + CDbl(Mid(str, i + 1, (j - (i + 1))))
                i = j
            End If
        Next i
End Function
```